# C++ increment operator overload as friend function not working?

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

I'm just going to preface this with the fact that I'm new to C++ so it's quite possible there's just a stupid error here, but I can't find it.

I'm just trying to overload the increment operator in a friend function. Everything compiles perfectly and everything works if I explicitly call the postfix increment overload:

```
operator++(*test, 0);
```

Every element in the matrix is incremented and the program prints it out using `cout` perfectly. The problem is when I try to do the normal ++ increment `test++;` it appears as though something wrong happens with the test pointer to where when it tries to print the test object it doesn't print anything.

Any idea what's going on? I'm clueless. Here's the code I'm working with...

Compile & Run

```
g++ -o App App.cpp Matrix.cpp
./App
```

App.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Matrix.h"

using namespace std;

#define X 9

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Start the actual program here
    Matrix* test = new Matrix(3,3);
    // Row 1
    test->setElement(0,0,1);
    test->setElement(0,1,2);
    test->setElement(0,2,3);
    // Row 2
    test->setElement(1,0,4);
    test->setElement(1,1,5);
    test->setElement(1,2,6);
    // Row 3
    test->setElement(2,0,7);
    test->setElement(2,1,8);
    test->setElement(2,2,9);

    operator++(*test, 0);
    //test++;
    //++test;

    // Print the Matrix object
    cout << *test << endl;
}
```

Matrix.h

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Matrix {
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Matrix&);
    friend Matrix& operator++(Matrix&);        // prefix increment
    friend Matrix& operator++(Matrix&, int);   // postfix increment
    private:
        int rows;
        int cols;
        int** elements;
    public:
        // Constructors
        Matrix(int);
        Matrix(int,int);
        Matrix(const Matrix&);
        // Define setters
        void setElement(int,int,int);
        // Define getters
        int getRowCount();
        int getColCount();
        int getElementAt(int,int);
        void increment();
        // Destructor
        ~Matrix();
};

#endif
```

Matrix.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Matrix.h"

using namespace std;

//===================================
//    DEFINE [CON]/[DE]STRUCTORS
//===================================
// Constructor for creating square matricies
Matrix::Matrix(int _size) {
    rows = _size;
    cols = _size;
    elements = new int*[_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++) {
        elements[i] = new int[_size];
    }
}

// Constructor for supporting non-square matricies
Matrix::Matrix(int _rows, int _cols) {
    rows = _rows;
    cols = _cols;
    elements = new int*[_rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < _rows; i++) {
        elements[i] = new int[_cols];
    }
}

// Copy constructor
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& mat1) {
    Matrix(mat1.rows, mat1.cols);

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            elements[i][j] = mat1.elements[i][j];
        }
    }
}

// Destructor
Matrix::~Matrix() {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        delete[] elements[i];
    }
    delete[] elements;
}

//===================================
//     DEFINE SETTER FUNCTIONS
//===================================
void Matrix::setElement(int row, int col, int newElement) {
    if (row > rows-1 || row < 0)
        throw "Row out of index";
    if (col > cols-1 || col < 0)
        throw "Column out of index";

    elements[row][col] = newElement;
}

//===================================
//     DEFINE GETTER FUNCTIONS
//===================================
int Matrix::getRowCount() { return rows; }

int Matrix::getColCount() { return cols; }

int Matrix::getElementAt(int row, int col) {
    if (row > rows-1 || row < 0)
        throw "Row out of index";
    if (col > cols-1 || col < 0)
        throw "Column out of index";

    return elements[row][col];
}

//===================================
//    OVERRIDE OPERATOR FUNCTIONS
//===================================
// Print the Matrix to the output stream
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Matrix& mat) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat.cols; j++) {
            out << mat.elements[i][j] << " ";
        }
        out << endl;
    }

    return out;
}

// Prefix. Increment immediately and return the object.
Matrix& operator++(Matrix& mat) {
    cout << "Prefix ++ operator" << endl;
    // Increment all elements in the object by 1
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat.cols; j++) {
            mat.elements[i][j] += 1;
        }
    }
    return mat;
}

// Postfix. Return the current object and "save" the incremented.
Matrix& operator++(Matrix& mat, int x) {
    cout << "Postfix ++ operator" << endl;
    // Save the current values
    Matrix* curVals = new Matrix(mat);
    // Increment the object
    ++(mat);
    // Return the unincremented values
    return *curVals;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a friend statement here ? IMO you should simply define your operator as a public function and simply use `(*test)++;` instead of calling the `operator++()` function... In this case, the prototype would simply be `Matrix& operator++();` and you might use `this->` instead of `mat.` in your implementation. Finally, mind that I think that you mixed up pre/post fixes

Comment: @J Faucher I normally would have made them public member functions, however I had a requirement to make them friend functions for this application. Also thanks for the warning, but the pre/post fixes are actually correct. I checked that many times when trying to figure out what my issue was here. The postfix includes an extra int parameter.

Comment: My total mistake then ! I always use postfix and always implemented it with a prefix declaration... Fortunately, I never worked on a pro project !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test++` increments the value of `test`, so that it will point to the memory after your `Matrix` object.  You need to dereference the pointer to get a `Matrix` object, then apply the increment to that.

What you want is `(*test)++` or `++*test`.

Comment: Wow...I had a feeling it would just be something stupid that I was overlooking. Can you tell I'm not completely used to working with pointers yet? Ha. Thanks!